# Is there a historical name for an inductor that starts with the letter $L$? (RL circuits)

Tags: soft-question, notation, history, inductance

Why is a circuit with a resistor and inductor called an RL circuit and not an RI circuit?

Was there a now-obsolete name for an inductor that started with the letter $L$?

Comment: We don't use m for momentum but we use p

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't contain a single gram of actual physics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoted from [Wikipedia: Inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance):

> It is customary to use the symbol $L$ for inductance, in honour of the physicist Heinrich Lenz.